# Automatically refresh Activity when Internet is there

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-networking

I have an `ActivityNonetwork.java` Activity. The purpose of that file is that when there is no network/internet, the `ActivityNonetwork` activity is shown.

I tried it, I turned off the internet and this page was shown (Successful!!!), but when I again turn on the internet, the page does not refresh and the same page is being shown even after I turn the internet on.

My `ActivityNonetwork.java` code:

```
package com.Notely.SplashScreenandAccounts;

import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedCallback;
import androidx.activity.OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.Notely.Notes.ActivityDashboard;

public class ActivityNonetwork extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nonetwork);

    final Button exit = findViewById(R.id.exit);
    final Button retry = findViewById(R.id.retry);

    exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            exitApp();
        }
    });
    retry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            retryApp();
        }
    });

    if (checkNetwork() == true) {
        finish();
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        startActivity(getIntent());
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

        Intent activitySplash = new Intent(this, ActivitySplash.class);
        startActivity(activitySplash);
    }
}

private boolean checkNetwork() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}

public void exitApp() {
    Intent exitApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    exitApp.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    exitApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(exitApp);
}

public void retryApp() {
    Intent retryApp = new Intent(this, ActivitySplash.class);
    startActivity(retryApp);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent exitApp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    exitApp.addCategory( Intent.CATEGORY_HOME );
    exitApp.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(exitApp);
}
}
```

Is there any way in which we can refresh the page when the internet comes?

Comment: You need to check internet connection in background, with foregroundService

Comment: what do you mean by refreshing the activity?? do you want any specific code block to be re ececuted or you want the activity to be recreated??

Comment: You can register a BroadcastReciver to check change in network state and based on it you can check where you are online or not. <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />  and if online, just refresh the activity!

Answer (score 0):

you just check network connection when activity created,
you have to initialize observer for network changes

read this [article](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing) and manage your network connection

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using broadcast receiver in your project

Create a class as below -

```
public class NetworkChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
   PrefManager.getInstance(context).setPreviousNetworkStatus
   (NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context));
 }
}
```

Then create below class -

```
class NetworkUtil {

private static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
private static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
private static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


private static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = context.getString(R.string.wifi_enabled);
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = context.getString(R.string.mobile_data_enable);
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = context.getString(R.string.not_connected_to_internet);
    }
    return status;
 }
}
```

Create a PrefsManager class -  This is not mandatory to create a separate class for this funcionality. You can add this code to your MainActivity.

```
public class PrefManager {

public static final String PREVIOUS_NETWORK_STATE = "previous_network_state";

private static SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private static PrefManager prefManager;

private PrefManager(Context context) {
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, 
    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

public static PrefManager getInstance(Context context) {
    if (prefManager == null) {
        prefManager = new PrefManager(context);
    }
    return prefManager;
}

public SharedPreferences getSharedPreferences() {
    return sharedPreferences;
}

public void setPreviousNetworkStatus(String status) {
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString(PREVIOUS_NETWORK_STATE, status).apply();
}

public String getPreviousNetworkStatus() {
    return sharedPreferences.getString(PREVIOUS_NETWORK_STATE, "");
}
}
```

In MainActivity

```
 private NetworkChangeReceiver networkChangeReceiver = NetworkChangeReceiver()
```

In onCreate method register receiver

```
 registerReceiver(
        networkChangeReceiver,
        IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
    )
```

Override below method

```
@Override void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String 
key) {
    if (key == PrefManager.PREVIOUS_NETWORK_STATE) {
        onNetworkChanged()
    }
 }
```

Then create this method -

```
private void onNetworkChanged() {
    // your code here 

    finish();
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
    startActivity(getIntent());
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

    Intent activitySplash = new Intent(this, ActivitySplash.class);
    startActivity(activitySplash);
}
```

unregister receiver in onDestroy method

```
 unregisterReceiver(networkChangeReceiver)
```

I hope this will work for you.